# Screen orientation Unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, screen

im trying to make change in my recttransform when the screen of the android became portrait or landscape, but the code just read the screenrotation portrait, the other never work. i dont know why.

```
    if (Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.Portrait)
    {
        rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0, 50);
        rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(800, 100);
    }

    if(Screen.orientation == ScreenOrientation.Landscape)
    {
        rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0, 33);
        rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(800, 75);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The API you're using (`Screen.orientation`) is for *setting* different orientation behaviors.  If you'd like to read the current value, you want [`Input.deviceOrientation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-deviceOrientation.html) and check against the [`DeviceOrientation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DeviceOrientation.html) object it returns:

```
if (Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.Portrait ||
    Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown)
{
}
else if (Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft ||
    Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight)
{
}
```

---

Also, to rule this out (just in case):  Make sure in the *ProjectSettings > Player* inspector, with Android selected, under "*Resolution and Presentation*", make sure your application is allowing the device to handle rotations with "*Default Orientation*" set to "*Auto Rotation*" and "*Allowed Orientations for Auto Rotation*" contains what you'd want it to.

Comment: @RicardoMendoza There are values other than those 4 that can be returned (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DeviceOrientation.html); I meant what I posted as an example.  A switch statement could be appropriate here but for starters, you can Debug.Log(Input.deviceOrientation) and observe it then write you conditional afterwards